# how to combine top_hits and date_histogram aggregation in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I would like to extract the date histogram from the result of top_hits aggregation. The code below returns every first "mydata" from every "myhash".

```
    {
      "aggs": {
        "agg_indexing": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "_index": "myindex"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_class": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "myhash",
                "size": 10000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "agg_top": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                      {
                        "mytime": {
                          "order": "asc"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "_source": {
                      "includes": [
                        "mytime",
                        "mydata"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So I would like to make this result as a histogram. And the code below is what I intended, but it doesn't work.

```
    {
      "aggs": {
        "agg_indexing": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "_index": "y_paylog"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_class": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "idhash",
                "size": 10000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "agg_top": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                      {
                        "logtime": {
                          "order": "asc"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "_source": {
                      "includes": [
                        "logtime",
                        "pay"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "hist_over_date": {
                      "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "mytime",
                        "interval": "24h"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "revenue_sum": {
                          "sum": {
                            "field": "mydata"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I think there must be another way to call the variable, not "mydata".

Thanks in advance.

++

```
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "agg_indexing": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "_index": "y_paylog"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_class": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "idhash",
                "size": 10000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "agg_hist": {
                  "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "logtime",
                    "interval": "24h"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "agg_top": {
                      "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                          {
                            "logtime": {
                              "order": "asc"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                          "includes": [
                            "logtime",
                            "pay"
                          ]
                        },
                        "size": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `top_hits` is a metric aggregation (not a bucket one) and as such it cannot have sub-aggregations.

Comment: @Val - I got it. Then is there any way to call back the result of the top_hits aggregation in that query?

Comment: How about having `terms:idhash` > `date_histogram:logtime` > `top_hits`? That would probably work right?

Comment: @Val - I have considered that one, but I thought that it would return the result of top_hits per logtime, and that is not what I wanted. Anyway, I'll try it and comment again. Thanks.

Comment: @Val - The result shows the histogram of every idhash.. I have no idea of where the top_hits actually worked here. I uploaded the code in the question above.

Comment: What I want to do is to create a histogram of first payments of the users.

Comment: And your latest aggregation should do exactly that, doesn't it?

Comment: @Val - yeah I did that, like I said, but the result isn't. The result shows the payment histograms of user#1, user#2, ..., user#10000, respectively. It isn't what I expected. And furthermore, there is no result of top_hits, I think. Maybe, there is need to somewhat edit the last code.